# How can I track button release events?

Tags: rust, x11, window-managers, xcb

I'm working on a simple window manager using XCB, and I need to be notified when the user clicks on the screen to obtain the ID of the window where the pointer was located.

I attempted to enable `XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE` for each new client using the following code:

```rust
let cookie = xcb::change_window_attributes_checked(
    conn,
    self.wid,
    &[(xcb::CW_EVENT_MASK, xcb::EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE)],
);

if let Err(cookie) = cookie.request_check() {
    panic!("error {:?}", cookie.to_string());
}
```

However, this approach doesn't seem to work, as even though the cookie is not in an error state, no `BUTTON_RELEASE` event is triggered.

I also experimented with `xcb_grab_button`, which successfully sends the event. However, the `BUTTON_RELEASE` event always contains the root window's ID, not the ID of the "focused" window. Additionally, this method blocks all clients from receiving mouse events:

```rust
xcb::grab_button(
    &self.conn,
    false,
    util::get_screen(&self.conn).root(),
    xcb::EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS as u16 | xcb::EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE as u16,
    xcb::GRAB_MODE_ASYNC as u8,
    xcb::GRAB_MODE_ASYNC as u8,
    xcb::NONE,
    xcb::NONE,
    1,
    xcb::MOD_MASK_ANY as u16,
);
```

Please note that the `XCB_EVENT_MASK_ENTER_WINDOW` and `XCB_EVENT_MASK_LEAVE_WINDOW` masks work fine. Additionally, `XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE` functions properly when set on the root window.